# When considering the torque exerted on one mass by another, is moment of inertia additive?

Tags: rotational-dynamics

To be specific: Consider a system with a disk rotating at a constant speed and a disk hovering above it, not rotating. When the hovering disk is dropped on to the rotating disk, we want to know the torque.   I know that the applied torque will be equal to I*angular acceleration, but would the I be just for the hovering disk applying the torque, or the total I for the two-disk system?

Comment: *we want to know the torque.* What torque specifically?

Comment: Torque applied by the disk that was dropped on the disk that was initially rotating

Answer (score 1):

The torque is applied in equal and opposite sense onto the two disks. The effect is that one disk is accelerating and the other decelerating but not with the same magnitude if their respective mass moments of inertia are different.

$$ \begin{aligned}
 \dot{\omega}_1 & = - \frac{\tau}{I_1} \\ \dot{\omega}_2 & = + \frac{\tau}{I_2}
\end{aligned} $$

You would only *add* the mass moment of inertias if the two bodies acted as a single rigid body. If there is a degree of freedom between them, then you can't add them.

The reason is that if you add up the total angular momentum of two disks spinning at different rates you have $$ L = I_1 \omega_1 + I_2 \omega_2$$ which cannot be simplified further. But, if they act as a rigid body with $\omega =  \omega_1 = \omega_2$ then

$$ L = \left( I_1 + I_2 \right) \omega $$ see how the two MMOI add up?

I hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, this helped a lot!